# Data transfer between mutiple fragments with only one activity running them all

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I have 1 fragment who accomplishe some calculation based on user inputs and a second fragment to witch the first fragment  transfer result of the calculation, my code work fine for transfere portion of it.I use intent to transfer data as show in the code below ( located in onClick method)

```
 **First Fragment**
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
 ActivityGestionFragment.class);
 intent.putExtra("REVENU_TOTAL", (double)total_revenu);
 getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

the probleme is each time i press the button of the first fragment for calculation and transfere data to second fragment a new screen of the main activity pop up  (data is transfered to the second fragment as expexted)
the trouble come from **startActivity(intent)** i am looking for  a way to prevent  **ActivityGestionFragment** initial layout from poping up each time i press the calculation button of the first fragment ( all  fragments and the main activity layout are displayed in FrameLayout and i use FragmentManager to manage Fragments)

the code below in the second fragment witch handel the comming Intent

```
    **second Fragment**

    impotFed = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textImpotFed);
    double revenu=  getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("REVENU_TOTAL");
    impotFed.setText(Double.toString(revenu*TAUX ));
```